# Fullcalendar update second calendar based on first

Tags: fullcalendar-4

I'm trying to update a second calendar based on the changes from the first. I've found the function calendar.view.activeStart; and calendar.view.type; which gives me the start date and the calendar type. I can use the changeView(); to update the type of the second calendar when loading the first time. But the date is in a format i can't use (Mon Jun 10 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time). How can i use the calendar.view to get the date and how can i update the second calendar with every change.

Here is the code i'm using.

```
var viewType = '';
var viewDate = '';

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
var Calendar = FullCalendar.Calendar;
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
    locale: 'nl',
    weekNumbers: true,
    defaultDate: standaarddatum,
    nowIndicator: true,
    height: 500,
    businessHours: true,
    editable:true,
    droppable: true,
    selectable:true,
    unselectAuto:true,
    plugins: [ 'interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'list' ],
    themeSystem: 'bootstrap',
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,listYear'
        },
    allDaySlot: false,
    defaultView: 'timeGridWeek',
    events: {
    url: 'load_select.php',
    method: 'POST',
    extraParams: function() { 
        return {
        cursus_id:localStorage.getItem("cursus_select"), evenement_id:localStorage.getItem("evenement_select"), locatie_id:localStorage.getItem("locatie_select"), trainer_id:localStorage.getItem("trainer_select")
        };
    },
    failure: function() {
        alert('er zijn geen cursussen met deze combinatie!');
        localStorage.setItem("cursus_select", '0');
        localStorage.setItem("evenement_select", '0');
        localStorage.setItem("locatie_select", '0');
        localStorage.setItem("trainer_select", '0');
        calendar.refetchEvents()
        $('#cursusselect').val('');
        $('#evenementselect').val('');
        $('#locatieselect').val('');
        $('#trainerselect').val('');
            }
        },
    });
    calendar.render();
    viewDate = calendar.view.activeStart;
    viewType = calendar.view.type;
});


        //TWEEDE


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
var Calendar = FullCalendar.Calendar;
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar10');
var calendar10 = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
    locale: 'nl',
    weekNumbers: true,
    defaultDate: standaarddatum,
    nowIndicator: true,
    height: 500,
    businessHours: true,
    editable:true,
    droppable: true,
    selectable:true,
    unselectAuto:true,
    plugins: [ 'interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'list' ],
    themeSystem: 'bootstrap',
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,listYear'
        },
    allDaySlot: false,
    defaultView: 'timeGridWeek',
    events: {
    url: 'load_select.php',
    method: 'POST',
    extraParams: function() {
        return {
        cursus_id:localStorage.getItem("cursus_select10"), evenement_id:localStorage.getItem("evenement_select10"), locatie_id:localStorage.getItem("locatie_select10"), trainer_id:localStorage.getItem("trainer_select10")
        };
    },
    failure: function() {
        alert('er zijn geen cursussen met deze combinatie!');
        localStorage.setItem("cursus_select", '0');
        localStorage.setItem("evenement_select", '0');
        localStorage.setItem("locatie_select", '0');
        localStorage.setItem("trainer_select", '0');
        calendar10.refetchEvents()
        $('#cursusselect10').val('');
        $('#evenementselect10').val('');
        $('#locatieselect10').val('');
        $('#trainerselect10').val('');
            }
        },
    });     
    calendar10.render();
    calendar10.changeView(viewType, viewDate);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

it works with gotoDate(); not changeView();